# Python PID simulation

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to simulate a control system in python.  This is what I have so far:

PID.py - functions to set Kp, Ki, Kd, and a function to generate an output based on an error. ex. PID.genout(err)

PIDPlot.py - plots the output based on a step input. here is a sample of the code:

```
for i in range(1, 51):

    # summing node
    err = sp - fb

    # PID block
    outv = pid.GenOut(err)

    # control feedback
    if sp > 0:
        fb += (outv - (1.0/i))

    # start with sp = 0, simulate a step input at t(10)
    if i > 5:
        sp = 10

    # add sp and outv to there lists
    sp_list.append(sp)
    fb_list.append(fb)
    sample_list.append(i * .05)



    time.sleep(.05)
```

I would like to change the part that controls the feedback so that it models my system (Plant) more closely, but that is where I get stuck.  I determined the transfer function of the system(plant) by applying a step and logging the output and plotting it. Based on the curve, dc gain and time constant I came up with  0.92/16s +1 for the transfer function.
When I plot the step response in Python like so:

```
from numpy import min, max
from scipy import linspace
from scipy.signal import lti, step

# making transfer function
# example from Ogata Modern Control Engineering 
# 4th edition, International Edition page 307

# num and den, can be list or numpy array type
num = [-0.93] 

#denominator of the form s^2 + s +1
den = [16, 1]

tf = lti(num, den)

# get t = time, s = unit-step response
t, s = step(tf)

# recalculate t and s to get smooth plot
t, s = step(tf, T = linspace(min(t), t[-1], 500))

# get i = impulse
#t, i = impulse(tf, T = linspace(min(t), t[-1], 500))

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#plt.plot(t, s, t, i)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.title('Transient-Response Analysis')
plt.xlabel('Time(sec)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.hlines(1, min(t), max(t), colors='r')
plt.hlines(0, min(t), max(t))
plt.xlim(xmax=max(t))
plt.legend(('Unit-Step Response',), loc=0)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

It matches my plotted data nicely.  Now how can I use this transfer function to generate the feedback in the PIDPlot? Then from there I can try to write code to auto tune the pid based on the system(plant).

Answer (score -1):

1. Generate the feedback in PIDPlot
   I didn't see the transfer function in the code, could you show me?
2. If you want to tune the PID and find the best Kp, Ki, Kd for your DC system, you need to considerate those kicks, changes in the chart. You need to dynamically control your PID constants, which means you need methods.

Here is a very useful blog talking about tuning PID in Python. I wrote an PID control algorithm before and grab some idea from this blog, it is very helpful.

http://brettbeauregard.com/blog/2011/04/improving-the-beginner%E2%80%99s-pid-tuning-changes/

```
/*working variables*/
unsigned long lastTime;
double Input, Output, Setpoint;
double ITerm, lastInput;
double kp, ki, kd;
int SampleTime = 1000; //1 sec
void Compute()
{
   unsigned long now = millis();
   int timeChange = (now - lastTime);
   if(timeChange>=SampleTime)
   {
      /*Compute all the working error variables*/
      double error = Setpoint - Input;
      ITerm += (ki * error);
      double dInput = (Input - lastInput);

      /*Compute PID Output*/
      Output = kp * error + ITerm - kd * dInput;

      /*Remember some variables for next time*/
      lastInput = Input;
      lastTime = now;
   }
}

void SetTunings(double Kp, double Ki, double Kd)
{
  double SampleTimeInSec = ((double)SampleTime)/1000;
   kp = Kp;
   ki = Ki * SampleTimeInSec;
   kd = Kd / SampleTimeInSec;
}

void SetSampleTime(int NewSampleTime)
{
   if (NewSampleTime > 0)
   {
      double ratio  = (double)NewSampleTime
                      / (double)SampleTime;
      ki *= ratio;
      kd /= ratio;
      SampleTime = (unsigned long)NewSampleTime;
   }
}
```

Hope this would help.